# How to convert the oracle sql to Snowflake sql

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hi I am calling a select query in a select, in Snowflake. I am facing the error as INVALID IDENTIFIER AS ROWNUM, when I comment Rownum, I am facing the error as Unsupported Subquery type cant evaluted.

My requirement is converting the existing oracle query to SNowflake.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT cust.Id AS Customer_Id
            ,nvl((
                    SELECT *
                    FROM (
                        SELECT to_char(cliterm.Quantity)
                        FROM ContractLineItemTerm cliterm
                        WHERE cliterm.ContractLineItem_id = cli.Id
                            AND (
                                cliterm.EndDate IS NULL
                                OR cliterm.EndDate > add_months(sysdate, - 3)
                                )
                            AND cliterm.PriceRuleItem_id IS NULL
                        ORDER BY cli.id DESC
                        )
                    WHERE rownum = 1
                    ), cli.Quantity) AS Quantity_Purchased
            ,nvl((
                    SELECT *
                    FROM (
                        SELECT cliterm.UsedQuantity
                        FROM ContractLineItemTerm cliterm
                        WHERE cliterm.ContractLineItem_id = cli.Id
                            AND (
                                cliterm.EndDate IS NULL
                                OR cliterm.EndDate > add_months(sysdate, - 3)
                                )
                            AND cliterm.PriceRuleItem_id IS NULL
                        ORDER BY cli.id DESC
                        )
                    WHERE rownum = 1
                    ), cli.UsedQuantity) AS Quantity_Used_To_Date
            ,nvl((
                    SELECT *
                    FROM (
                        SELECT cliterm.StartDate
                        FROM ContractLineItemTerm cliterm
                        WHERE cliterm.ContractLineItem_id = cli.Id
                            AND (
                                cliterm.EndDate IS NULL
                                OR cliterm.EndDate > add_months(sysdate, - 3)
                                )
                            AND cliterm.PriceRuleItem_id IS NULL
                        ORDER BY cli.id DESC
                        )
                    WHERE rownum = 1
                    ), cli.StartDate) AS sbscription_Term_Start_Date
            ,nvl((
                    SELECT *
                    FROM (
                        SELECT cliterm.EndDate
                        FROM ContractLineItemTerm cliterm
                        WHERE cliterm.ContractLineItem_id = cli.Id
                            AND (
                                cliterm.EndDate IS NULL
                                OR cliterm.EndDate > add_months(sysdate, - 3)
                                )
                            AND cliterm.PriceRuleItem_id IS NULL
                        ORDER BY id DESC
                        )
                    WHERE rownum = 1
                    ), cli.EndDate) AS sbscription_Term_End_Date
            ,nvl(to_char(cli.EndDate), (
                    CASE 
                        WHEN (
                                cli.StartDate IS NOT NULL
                                AND con.InitialTerm > 0
                                )
                            THEN 'Auto Renewal'
                        ELSE ''
                        END
                    )) AS Contr_End_Date
        FROM ContractLineItem cli
        INNER JOIN Contract con ON cli.Contract_id = con.Id
        INNER JOIN Customer cust ON con.Customer_id = cust.Id
        INNER JOIN Organization org ON org.Customer_id = cust.Id
        INNER JOIN Product prod ON cli.Product_id = prod.Id
        INNER JOIN Producttype pt ON prod.ProductBrand_id = pt.Id
        LEFT JOIN account acc ON cust.SAN = acc.acc__c
        LEFT JOIN account acc1 ON acc.parentid = acc1.id
        LEFT JOIN sbSCRIPTION sb ON sb.id = cli.sforceid
        LEFT JOIN sbSCRIPTION pasb ON pasb.id = sb.srequired
        LEFT JOIN scontract1 cntr ON cntr.contractnumber = con.ContNumber
        LEFT JOIN user accowner ON acc.ownerid = accowner.id
        LEFT JOIN user accsalesmanager ON accowner.managerid = accsalesmanager.id
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT f.accountid
                ,g.managerid
                ,max(g.NAME) CSM
                ,max(g.id) CSMID
            FROM accountteammember f
            JOIN user g ON f.userid = g.id
            WHERE f.teammemberrole = 'AGM'
            GROUP BY f.accountid
                ,g.managerid
            ) acccsm ON acccsm.accountid = acc.id
        LEFT JOIN product2 prd ON prod.Code = prd.productcode
        LEFT JOIN prdfam prod_fam ON prod_fam.product_family_desc = prd.Product_Family__c
        )
    WHERE Quantity_Purchased <> 0
    );
```

How to convert the same to snowflake supported, as it should pick the quantity column based on rownum=1, if it is null, it should be replaced by some x.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full SQL statement; you don't need to provide all the columns in the SELECT but you do need to include all the tables and their join logic

Comment: I mentioned the full oracle sql query, Now this need to be changed as per Snowflake. Please suggest the changes.

Comment: Hi - the ORDER BY cli.id in each of your sub-selects is not going to do anything as the SELECT is limited to a single id anyway (from the join). If these sub-selects ever return more than one record then you will be getting a random selection - which I assume is not what you want. For each cli.id, what is the correct logic to determine which record to return from each sub-select, if there are more than one?

Answer (score 0):

Try and change your query to this (change `WHERE rownum = 1` to `limit 1` :

```sql
,nvl((
                    SELECT *
                    FROM (
                        SELECT to_char(cliterm.Quantity)
                        FROM ContractLineItemTerm cliterm
                        WHERE cliterm.ContractLineItem_id = cli.Id
                            AND (
                                cliterm.EndDate IS NULL
                                OR cliterm.EndDate > add_months(sysdate, - 3)
                                )
                            AND cliterm.PriceRuleItem_id IS NULL
                        ORDER BY cli.id DESC
                        )
                    limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The example SQL is missing a couple layers of `SELECT * FROM (` as you have to unmatched paren at the end. But assuming you are selecting * so your `WHERE Quantity_Purchased <> 0` this can be coverted to a QUALIFY and the layers can be skipped.

There are two main things, how to convert the SQL, and how to avoid the corrolated sub-query

firstly the three sub-select in the JOIN have the same pattern, so we will talk about the first one, `WHERE rownum = 1` can been done via a `limit 1` order via `QUALIFY` I prefer the latter.

```
SELECT to_char(cliterm.Quantity)
FROM ContractLineItemTerm cliterm
WHERE cliterm.ContractLineItem_id = cli.Id
    AND (
        cliterm.EndDate IS NULL
        OR cliterm.EndDate > add_months(sysdate, - 3)
        )
    AND cliterm.PriceRuleItem_id IS NULL
QUALIFY row_numumber() OVER (ORDER BY cli.id DESC) = 1
```

then as you use this in the corrolated sub-query, which is actually also random, because you are ordering by `cli.id` but also joining on that same clause, so you in effect are not sorting your data. So firstly you need to have a better clause for selecting from `ContractLineItemTerm` I am going to make up a column called `is_best` just so the SQL makes sense, and then you can put something in there that, makes sense.

The next thing to note is your four selects are all the same SQL block, so we can change this to one join and be done with it.

so I have used a CTE just so you can see how the fours blocks where written as one, and reformatted your `JOIN` `ON`'s to be on new lines, as for more complex SQL it is nicer, and I rewrote your `CASE` to be an `IFF` as it is a simple two branch case.

```
WITH best_per_id (
    SELECT cliterm.ContractLineItem_id
        ,to_char(cliterm.Quantity) as Quantity
        ,cliterm.UsedQuantity
        ,cliterm.StartDate
    FROM ContractLineItemTerm cliterm
    WHERE cliterm.PriceRuleItem_id IS NULL
        AND (
            cliterm.EndDate IS NULL
            OR cliterm.EndDate > add_months(sysdate, - 3)
            )
    QUALIFY row_numumber() OVER (PARTITION BY cliterm.ContractLineItem_id 
        ORDER BY cliterm.is_best ) = 1
)
SELECT DISTINCT cust.Id AS Customer_Id
    ,nvl(bpi.Quantity, cli.Quantity) AS Quantity_Purchased
    ,nvl(bpi.UsedQuantity, cli.UsedQuantity) AS Quantity_Used_To_Date
    ,nvl(bpi.StartDate, cli.StartDate) AS sbscription_Term_Start_Date
    ,nvl(bpi.EndDate, cli.EndDate) AS sbscription_Term_End_Date
    ,nvl(to_char(cli.EndDate), 
         IFF(cli.StartDate IS NOT NULL AND con.InitialTerm > 0, 'Auto Renewal', '')
        ) AS Contr_End_Date
FROM ContractLineItem cli
INNER JOIN Contract con 
    ON cli.Contract_id = con.Id
INNER JOIN Customer cust 
    ON con.Customer_id = cust.Id
INNER JOIN Organization org 
    ON org.Customer_id = cust.Id
INNER JOIN Product prod 
    ON cli.Product_id = prod.Id
INNER JOIN Producttype pt 
    ON prod.ProductBrand_id = pt.Id
LEFT JOIN best_per_id as bpi
    ON cli.id = bpi.ContractLineItem_id
LEFT JOIN account acc 
    ON cust.SAN = acc.acc__c
LEFT JOIN account acc1 
    ON acc.parentid = acc1.id
LEFT JOIN sbSCRIPTION sb 
    ON sb.id = cli.sforceid
LEFT JOIN sbSCRIPTION pasb 
    ON pasb.id = sb.srequired
LEFT JOIN scontract1 cntr 
    ON cntr.contractnumber = con.ContNumber
LEFT JOIN user accowner 
    ON acc.ownerid = accowner.id
LEFT JOIN user accsalesmanager 
    ON accowner.managerid = accsalesmanager.id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT f.accountid
        ,g.managerid
        ,max(g.NAME) CSM
        ,max(g.id) CSMID
    FROM accountteammember f
    JOIN user g ON f.userid = g.id
    WHERE f.teammemberrole = 'AGM'
    GROUP BY f.accountid
        ,g.managerid
    ) acccsm ON acccsm.accountid = acc.id
LEFT JOIN product2 prd 
    ON prod.Code = prd.productcode
LEFT JOIN prdfam prod_fam 
    ON prod_fam.product_family_desc = prd.Product_Family__c
QUALIFY Quantity_Purchased <> 0;
```

but that can all be written as a subselect like is done with `acccsm` like so:

```
WITH best_per_id (
    SELECT cliterm.ContractLineItem_id
        ,to_char(cliterm.Quantity) as Quantity
        ,cliterm.UsedQuantity
        ,cliterm.StartDate
    FROM ContractLineItemTerm cliterm
    WHERE cliterm.PriceRuleItem_id IS NULL
        AND (
            cliterm.EndDate IS NULL
            OR cliterm.EndDate > add_months(sysdate, - 3)
            )
    QUALIFY row_numumber() OVER (PARTITION BY cliterm.ContractLineItem_id 
       ORDER BY cliterm.is_best ) = 1
)
SELECT DISTINCT cust.Id AS Customer_Id
    ,nvl(bpi.Quantity, cli.Quantity) AS Quantity_Purchased
    ,nvl(bpi.UsedQuantity, cli.UsedQuantity) AS Quantity_Used_To_Date
    ,nvl(bpi.StartDate, cli.StartDate) AS sbscription_Term_Start_Date
    ,nvl(bpi.EndDate, cli.EndDate) AS sbscription_Term_End_Date
    ,nvl(to_char(cli.EndDate), 
         IFF(cli.StartDate IS NOT NULL AND con.InitialTerm > 0, 'Auto Renewal', '')
        ) AS Contr_End_Date
FROM ContractLineItem cli
INNER JOIN Contract con 
    ON cli.Contract_id = con.Id
INNER JOIN Customer cust 
    ON con.Customer_id = cust.Id
INNER JOIN Organization org 
    ON org.Customer_id = cust.Id
INNER JOIN Product prod 
    ON cli.Product_id = prod.Id
INNER JOIN Producttype pt 
    ON prod.ProductBrand_id = pt.Id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT cliterm.ContractLineItem_id
        ,to_char(cliterm.Quantity) as Quantity
        ,cliterm.UsedQuantity
        ,cliterm.StartDate
    FROM ContractLineItemTerm cliterm
    WHERE cliterm.PriceRuleItem_id IS NULL
        AND (
            cliterm.EndDate IS NULL
            OR cliterm.EndDate > add_months(sysdate, - 3)
            )
    QUALIFY row_numumber() OVER (PARTITION BY cliterm.ContractLineItem_id ORDER BY cliterm.is_best ) = 1
) as bpi
    ON cli.id = bpi.ContractLineItem_id
LEFT JOIN account acc 
    ON cust.SAN = acc.acc__c
LEFT JOIN account acc1 
    ON acc.parentid = acc1.id
LEFT JOIN sbSCRIPTION sb 
    ON sb.id = cli.sforceid
LEFT JOIN sbSCRIPTION pasb 
    ON pasb.id = sb.srequired
LEFT JOIN scontract1 cntr 
    ON cntr.contractnumber = con.ContNumber
LEFT JOIN user accowner 
    ON acc.ownerid = accowner.id
LEFT JOIN user accsalesmanager 
    ON accowner.managerid = accsalesmanager.id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT f.accountid
        ,g.managerid
        ,max(g.NAME) CSM
        ,max(g.id) CSMID
    FROM accountteammember f
    JOIN user g ON f.userid = g.id
    WHERE f.teammemberrole = 'AGM'
    GROUP BY f.accountid
        ,g.managerid
    ) acccsm ON acccsm.accountid = acc.id
LEFT JOIN product2 prd 
    ON prod.Code = prd.productcode
LEFT JOIN prdfam prod_fam 
    ON prod_fam.product_family_desc = prd.Product_Family__c
QUALIFY Quantity_Purchased <> 0;
```